# Why is my ActiveRecord (v6) `before_destroy` callback not firing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model where `X` can contain many `Y`'s, and a `Y` can contain many `Z`'s. It's a tree -- a child can not belong to more than one parent.

The put statements show me that the `before_destroy` callback isn't firing when I call `y.delete`, but the `delete` method is.

I can obviously just put the hook in the `delete` method, but am curious why the destroy callback doesn't work. I have `before_create` callbacks in this app, and they work fine.

```
class Y < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :do_before_destroy, prepend: true
  belongs_to :x
  has_many :zs, dependent: :destroy

  def delete
    puts "in delete"
    super
  end

private

  def do_before_destroy
    puts "do_before_destroy"
    self.zes.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [`destroy`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy). Some methods in *ActiveRecord* do not trigger callbacks, `delete` is one of them:

> The row is simply removed with an SQL DELETE statement on the record’s primary key, and **no callbacks are executed**.
> ...
> To enforce the object’s `before_destroy` and `after_destroy` callbacks or any `:dependent` association options, **use `destroy`**.

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete*

Comment: okthx. For some reason I thought it was the opposite, as `delete` feels less draconian than `destroy`.